# Scheme-less URL's in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the following code in a Laravel blade template to output a URL:

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

This outputs the URL like this:

```
<script src="http://example.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I want it to output like this:

```
<script src="//example.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I know that Laravel provides a way to output the protocol as https, but I'd prefer to use scheme-less URL's when linking to assets.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URL::asset` will only give `http` or `https`:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L146
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L188

There are probably some better asset management solutions out there than Laravel's default solution. Laravel does a lot of things VERY well, but in some cases like this, in order to minimize bloat, it provides only basic functionality and expects the developer to use a better 3rd party Composer package for more advanced features.